# How to retain a text in textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link the purpose of the link is to add a textfield dynamically when i click it. But the problem is that if i have entered a text in the previous generated textfield and click on the link, textfield is generated but the page refresh and the input text resets.

html file

```
<script>
    var countBox =3;
    var boxName = 0;
    function addInput()
    {
        var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
    document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br /><input type="radio" name="choices"  value="o'+countBox+'" id="o'+countBox+'"/><label>Option '+countBox+':</label> <input type="text" id="option'+countBox+'" name="option'+countBox+'"" placeholder="Enter here..."  /><br/>';
        countBox += 1;
    }
</script>
<br /><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="addInput()">Add another</a>(max.5)
```

How can i add the textfield and also retain the the text in the textfield. Hope you understood my problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to save the state of the page between refreshes? Cookies.

Comment: data will be lost on page refresh untill you use some session or cookies concept in your code!!!!

Comment: try to append the input types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page is **not** refreshed, so that's not the problem. The problem is that you are using `.innerHTML +=` to add the new elements. This is will *destroy* and *recreate* the existing elements: The elements are serialized to HTML, then you are concatenating the string to add new HTML and after the assignment the browser has to parse the HTML to create DOM Elements again. In this process all data will be lost.

Use DOM manipulation methods instead. I.e. create the elements with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and add them with [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Using `.innerHTML` to override existing content or to initialize an element for the first time is OK. But using it to *add* elements to an existing element can lead to problems (as mentioned above) so it is better avoided in this case.

Example:

```
function addInput() {
    var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = input.name = 'option'+countBox;

    var parent = document.getElementById('responce');
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    parent.appendChild(input);
    // create/add other elements...
    countBox += 1;
}
```

Or a mix of both:

```
function addInput() {
    var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="choices"  value="o'+countBox+'" id="o'+countBox+'"/><label>Option '+countBox+':</label> <input type="text" id="option'+countBox+'" name="option'+countBox+'"" placeholder="Enter here..."  />';

    document.getElementById('responce').appendChild(container);
    countBox += 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was posting the same but this says it all, anyway this is my fiddle with the full conversion http://jsfiddle.net/UkeuH/